# PostDispatch: Report Actual Weight but Charge Different Fee

Tags: extrinsic, weight, fee

Given the following extrinsic

```
#[pallet::weight(<T as Config>::WeightInfo::foo(*hint))]
fn foo(hint: u32) {
   let real = get_real();

   if real > hint {
      return <Error<T>>::HintTooLow;
   }

   // do something
   Ok(real.into())
}
```

Is it possible to report the actual weight (`real`) but charge a different fee (`hint`) from within the extrinsic? `PostDispatch` seems to affect the weight & subsequently the fee via `WeightToFee`. Probably what is desired here is a different weight to correct block weight and to charge fee, separately.

Rationale: Prevent a user from spamming the network by maliciously overestimating the hint thereby tricking block authors, tx priority, etc.

Comment: I'd have a look at this and please let us know if there is still something unclear: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/calculating-actual-weights-for-extrinsics

Comment: I looked into it and the concepts are quite clear to me, however, it doesn't address the question - can one report the actual weight used but charge fee on a different weight to disincentivize spamming extrinsics with a higher weight hint to maliciously trick the tx pool?

Comment: I don't fully understand your reasoning, but yes you can. You could write your own pallet where you implement the post-dispatch logic differently.

Comment: Yeah seems I'd either need to modify `transaction-payment` or write my own payment pallet to take into account the `DispatchInfo` & `PostDispatchInfo` weights for charging fees.

Answer (score 0):

I coincidentally bumped into this question. Assuming though that you meant the following:

```
#[pallet::weight(<T as Config>::WeightInfo::foo(*hint))]
fn foo(hint: u32) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
   let real = get_real();

   if real > hint {
      return <Error<T>>::HintTooLow.with_weight(T::WeightInfo::foo(real);
   }

   // do something
   Ok(Some(T::WeightInfo::foo(real)).into())
}
```

I would like to explain what will happen and what are the dangers:

When a block author is building a block it goes to its tx pool and finds this tx on top (most priority) and will run its respective weight function => `foo(hint)` in your case (to be found in the pallet's `weights.rs`). If there is enough weight left in the block, meaning the resulting weight of `foo(hint)` (the [`DispatchInfo`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/dispatch/struct.DispatchInfo.html)) is less than the available weight left in the block, the block author will include it in the block and validate and apply the extrinsic.

Now the extrinsic's logic will be executed and because your return value is  the [`DispatchResultWithPostInfo`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/dispatch/type.DispatchResultWithPostInfo.html) you can give [`PostDispatchInfo`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/dispatch/struct.DispatchInfo.html).
This will be the actual weight that will be accounted for in the block and what the user will pay for in terms of fees. In the other case where an extrinsic has the return value [`DispatchResult`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/dispatch/type.DispatchResult.html). The user will pay for the weight determined when authoring the block => `DispatchInfo`.

In your case I assume you would like to return the `real` weight in any scenario (failing or successfully executing the extrinsic) since otherwise your chain could be spammed. Why?

If for example we would change `real` -> `hint`:

```
if real > hint {
    return Error<T>::HintTooLow.with_weight(T::WeightInfo::foo(hint));
}
```

Someone could spam your chain with `hint == 0` and not having to pay a dime for the execution and therefore spamming your chain for free.

I still do not understand what you are trying to accomplish or why, but I hope this can be useful for others in the future.